# usermod command is not working despite giving permission in sudoers file

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo, sudoers

i have given linda user to run 2 commands (useradd & usermod) from the sudoers file, i successfully ran the useradd command but the problem is i can not run usermod command, i have checked everything by inserting comma in sudoers, rebooting, log-off & log-on but nothing works.

here you can check the status

```
[student@localhost ~]$ sudo grep linda /etc/sudoers
[sudo] password for student: 
linda   ALL=/usr/sbin/useradd, /usr/sbin/usermod    ALL
[student@localhost ~]$ su - linda
Password: 
[linda@localhost ~]$ sudo usermod -aG IT junaid
[sudo] password for linda: 
Sorry, user linda is not allowed to execute '/sbin/usermod -aG IT junaid' as root on localhost.localdomain.
[linda@localhost ~]$ sudo /usr/sbin/usermod -aG IT junaid
[sudo] password for linda: 
Sorry, user linda is not allowed to execute '/usr/sbin/usermod -aG IT junaid' as root on localhost.localdomain.
```

note that user linda is only member of their own group linda,

here's the full sudoers file

```
[student@localhost ~]$ sudo grep -v '#' /etc/sudoers | cat -s

Defaults   !visiblepw

Defaults    always_set_home
Defaults    match_group_by_gid

Defaults    always_query_group_plugin

Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    env_keep =  "COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE KDEDIR LS_COLORS"
Defaults    env_keep += "MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY"

Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

root    ALL=(ALL)   ALL
linda   ALL=/usr/sbin/useradd, /usr/sbin/usermod    ALL

%wheel  ALL=(ALL)   ALL
```

EDIT:
linda is not wheel group member

i also tried giving rights to linda from sudeors in separate lines, check grep result, but no effect

```
[student@localhost ~]$ sudo grep 'linda' /etc/sudoers
linda   ALL=/usr/sbin/useradd   ALL
linda   ALL=/usr/sbin/usermod   ALL
[student@localhost ~]$ su - linda
Password: 
[linda@localhost ~]$ sudo usermod -aG IT junaid
[sudo] password for linda: 
Sorry, user linda is not allowed to execute '/sbin/usermod -aG IT junaid' as root on localhost.localdomain.
```

here's sudo -l for linda

```
[student@localhost ~]$ sudo visudo 
[student@localhost ~]$ sudo grep 'linda' /etc/sudoers
linda   ALL=/usr/sbin/useradd, /usr/sbin/usermod    ALL
[student@localhost ~]$ su - linda
Password: 
[linda@localhost ~]$ sudo -l
[sudo] password for linda: 
Matching Defaults entries for linda on localhost:
    !visiblepw, always_set_home, match_group_by_gid, always_query_group_plugin, env_reset, env_keep="COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE
    KDEDIR LS_COLORS", env_keep+="MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE", env_keep+="LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION
    LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES", env_keep+="LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE", env_keep+="LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE
    LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY", secure_path=/sbin\:/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin

User linda may run the following commands on localhost:
    (root) /usr/sbin/useradd, /usr/sbin/usermod ALL
```

Comment: Did you edit sudoers using visudo?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille yes,

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution, i have to add groupadd rights as well

```
linda   ALL=/usr/sbin/useradd, /usr/sbin/usermod, /usr/sbin/groupadd    ALL
```

once i add /usr/sbin/groupadd in the sudoers now i can use usermod command to add users in the group

thanks everyone for your support :-)